# can't open android app from menu/ problems with permisions

Tags: android

I have a problem with launching this app through menu. There is no problem when I start it using a different application that has permission. This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.michael.dangerouslab" >


   <uses-permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"/>

    <permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM">
        <activity android:name=".DangerDanger" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete both occurrences of `android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"` (one in `<application>`, one in `<activity>`).

Those say "no third-party app, including the home screen, can do anything with my app, unless they have `<uses-permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"/>` in their manifest". There are roughly zero apps that have such an element, including roughly zero home screen implementations. Hence, you will not be able to launch your app.